# BFG repo cleaner not cleaning repository on remote

Tags: git, azure-devops, repository, git-history, git-history-rewrite

Hello I have a very big git repository of 13.2 gb on azure devops. I wanted rewrite the history of this git repository. To reduce the repository size. I used the bfg repo cleaner. I followed all the steps from this link :[enter link description here][1]. git repository size was reduced to 1,86 GB on my local repository. But when i clone the remote repository it is stil 13.2 gb big. although I was able to push the git successfully.

steps I followed:

1. java -jar bfg.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 100M some-big-repo.git
2. $ cd some-big-repo.git
   $ git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
3. git push --force

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If yes, you could accept it as an answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. If not, please let us know if you would like further assistance

Answer (score 0):

In the azure devops repo, please make sure you have set the 'Force push (rewrite history, delete branches and tags)' to 'Allow'. And please make sure your account has the Force push access.
And since your local repo has been reduced, you can try to import your local repo to a new Azure git repo. This will also including the all histories.
[image]

By the way, you seem not upload the link, so I don't know what steps you are doing.